# jquery not unbinding a "resize" bind done in a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that does:

`$(window).resize(setOverlayHeight)
          .resize(setSelfPosition)`

and I cant remove it in the main js code...

I have tried:

`$(window).off("resize", "setOverlayHeight");`

and

`$(window).unbind('resize', 'setSelfPosition');`

http://jsfiddle.net/VVqFn/3/

Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: I did try without '', but it was worthless. Apparently, the only way was to modify the plugin... (see comments on the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference, not a string.

```
$(window).off("resize", setOverlayHeight);
```

In order to remove all event bindings on window you can just do:

```
$(window).off();
```

Comment: I have done that too, but it says:Uncaught ReferenceError: setOverlayHeight is not defined

Comment: @VictorSoares He answered your question. the error is related with the codes that you have not shared.

Comment: @VictorSoares That is because the function is not in the scope where you are trying to turn it off. Can you show more code on where your function is?

Comment: @VictorSoares If you think resize is the only thing that has been attached to window you can just turn off everything by calling `.off()`

Comment: The event comes from this plugin: http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/... it is a normal plugin: (function...)(jQuery);

Comment: but I was trying to turn the events off, because the plugin let them there once it finishes doing what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @VictorSoares where have you defined `setOverlayHeight` and `setSelfPosition` ? Can you put together a fiddle?

Comment: @VictorSoares In that case extend the plugin to add your own function to turn off the event and invoke that method on `$(window)`. Can you show the plugin code in the fiddle?

Comment: I cant turn everything off, because I have other resize events that I need

Comment: @VictorSoares I see what you are saying it seems like a bug. You should n't be doing it, plug in should have handled it, even after destroy it doesn't destroy it.

Comment: @VictorSoares the plugin is not extensible as well, Only way i think os doing it is adding the missing unbind in `closeLightbox`, just add ` $(window).unbind('resize', setOverlayHeight);
                $(window).unbind('resize', setSelfPosition);` in the plugin code. Since they are defined local to the plugin you cannot access it. But it is maintenance headache better switch to another one. http://jsfiddle.net/EsRHy/

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I did... I was trying to avoid touching the plugin code.. but seems to be the only way...
Thanks evebody.